# Subtracting time in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to subtract time from each other based on a case condition 
but  the error is am getting is non-numeric character found where numeric character was expected

HERE IS THE CODE

```
select 
       case 
       when to_date('01-JAN-2019 05:00 AM', 'HH:MI:SS AM') < 
            to_date('01-JAN-2019 05:00 PM', 'HH:MI:SS AM') 
       then round((to_date('01-JAN-2019 05:00 AM', 'HH:MI:SS AM') - 
                   to_date('01-JAN-2019 09:00 AM', 'HH:MI:SS AM'))*24,2)
       else 0  
       end late
  from dual
```

Comment: Add format also for day, month and year

Comment: You are using wrong mask to convert date. In your case convert date with 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI AM' mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be using ISO 8601 standard timestamp format as

```
select case 
       when timestamp'2019-01-01 05:00:00' < timestamp'2019-01-01 17:00:00'
       then 
            timestamp'2019-01-01 05:00:00' - timestamp'2019-01-01 09:00:00'
       else interval '0' second
       end as late
  from dual
```

If you need numeric value for hour only, then consider :

```
select case 
       when timestamp'2019-01-01 05:00:00' < timestamp'2019-01-01 17:00:00'
       then 
          extract( hour from timestamp'2019-01-01 05:00:00' 
                           - timestamp'2019-01-01 09:00:00' )
       else 0
       end as late
  from dual
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c6d438930ac162bd6852ef9e1d717928)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You have to match date format and format mask:

```
SQL> select
  2  round(
  3        (to_date('01-JAN-2019 05:00 AM', 'dd-mon-yyyy HH:MI AM') -
  4         to_date('01-JAN-2019 09:00 AM', 'dd-mon-yyyy HH:MI AM')
  5        ) * 24, 2) result
  6  from dual;

    RESULT
----------
        -4

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks just found that out as well. i will run my code again. i didnt need the  date part. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First conversion format and real string format must match. Next, convert date to timestamp before substracting, so the result is interval. Finally, extract parts needed from the interval

```
select 
    extract( day from diff ) Days, 
    extract( hour from diff ) Hours, 
    extract( minute from diff ) Minutes 
from (
    select  CAST(to_date('01-JAN-2019 09:00 AM', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI AM') as timestamp) 
              - CAST(to_date('01-JAN-2019 05:00 AM', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI AM') as timestamp) diff   
    from dual
 )
```